# ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' - a different one

Tags: git, jenkins

Started getting this error after doing Build Now in Jenkins:

Started by user anonymous Building remotely on Ranorex in workspace

```
d:\Workspaces\Ranorex

Deleting project workspace... done

Cloning the remote Git repository Cloning repository https://365agile.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/365Agile/_git/365Agile.Ranorex
 > c:\git\bin\git.exe init d:\Workspaces\Ranorex # timeout=10 Fetching upstream changes from https://365agile.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/365Agile/_git/365Agile.Ranorex
 > c:\git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10 using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > c:\git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Users\JENKIN~1.SER\AppData\Local\Temp\git199499054612009523.credentials\"
# timeout=10
 > c:\git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://365agile.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/365Agile/_git/365Agile.Ranorex
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=15
 > c:\git\bin\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' Finished: FAILURE
```

I did have a successful build yesterday:

```
> d:\Workspaces\Ranorex>exit 0  Finished: SUCCESS
```

There have been minor changes to the application being tested but the configuration has not changed.

I am using MS Visual Studio GIT.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I have logged on to the Jenkins Slave & tried out the commands above line by line in the Command Prompt window. After entering the line: c:\git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://365agile.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/365Agile/_git/365Agile.Ranorex
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* - I get the error: fatal: Not a git repository

Comment: After a little tinkering, the error I am getting now running that same command (c:\git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress <Repo-URL> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*) is Authentication failed for <Repo-URL>

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins by default uses 'jenkins' user to execute a job. You need to create / generate SSH key for this jenkins user and add it.

As you say you started this job with the user anonymous. Did you run it yesterday with the same user? From the same place?

Comment: Yes. Yesterdays job was started by user anonymous and finished successfully. It was run from exactly the same place. All I did was click Build Now.